# sails.js : using dust in sails 0.10.5

Tags: sails.js, dust.js

I am trying to migrate a project from 0.9.9 to 0.10.5

We were using dust templating engine in our porject instead of the default ejs engine.

Contents of config/views.js file

```
module.exports.views = {
  engine: 'dust',
  layout: 'layout'
};
```

In my controller, I was able to render this view like this

```
res.view('layout', obj);
```

However, in sails 0.10.5, when I lift sails, first of all I get this warning

```
warn: Sails' built-in layout support only works with the `ejs` view engine.
warn: You're using `dust`.
warn: Ignoring `sails.config.views.layout`...
```

And then when I try to render the view as I was doing earlier, I get following error:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 Error: ENOENT, open '/.dust'

 { [Error: ENOENT, open '/.dust'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/.dust' }
```

Any idea what is the correct way of doing this in 0.10.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

The `layout` property does not apply to dust (just ejs). Set layout to `false` to get the warning to go away. You want to use Dust's built-in support for partials and blocks anyways.

Using `res.view('layout', obj);` means that you expect a file called `views/layout.dust` to exist. Prior to 0.10, sails was including the `layout` property from config/views.js as part of the path.

So my best guess is that your `res.view()` call is actually being invoked with an empty string as the first parameter, and it wasn't breaking because you were trying to render something called `layout`. I'd check your invocation to make sure that you're calling `res.view()` with an instantiated variable.

Comment: layout.dust file exists in the same location where layout.ejs is present. Also, I am not passing any variable in res.view but the plain string 'layout'. It was working fine earlier in 0.9.9
Will try with layout: false in config.

Comment: @mandeep_m91 Just go to config/views.js and set layout to false.